# fluent validation with when on client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation, fluentvalidation

In a ASP.NET MVC4 application we are using FluentValidation for validating our models. In certain cases we only want to validate a property when another property has a value. We use the When keyword to accomplish this. A simple validation class looks like this:

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(item => item.FirstName).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(item => item.LastName).NotEmpty().When(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FirstName))
    }
}
```

We would like to have client side validation for this. I tried to create a custom FluentValidationPropertyValidator. But I can't find a way to pickup the When part of the validation rule.
Can someone point me in right direction?

Comment: after some more research found out this would require a lot of work, more info: https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/229346

Answer (score 1):

FluentValidation does now support client-side validation. The following validators are supported on the client:

- NotNull/NotEmpty
- Matches (regex)
- InclusiveBetween (range)
- CreditCard
- Email
- EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
- MaxLength
- MinLength
- Length

https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet

Answer (score 0):

Some of validations in FluentValidation just don't support client-side validation:

From Documentation (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation):

> Note that FluentValidation will also work with ASP.NET MVC's
>   client-side validation, but not all rules are supported. For example,
>   any rules defined using a condition (with When/Unless), custom
>   validators, or calls to Must will not run on the client side. The
>   following validators are supported on the client:
>
> *NotNull/NotEmpty
>   *Matches (regex)
>   *InclusiveBetween (range)
>   *CreditCard
>   *Email
>   *EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
>   *Length

Answer (score 0):

Fluent Validation is a **server-side** validation library. But It supports some basic client-validations like required, maxlength etc.

If you want to add fully client-side support to Fluent Validation, you can use [**Form Helper**](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper).

You need to create your forms like this:

```
var formConfig = new FormConfig(ViewContext)
{
    FormId = "ProductForm",
    FormTitle = "New Product",
    BeforeSubmit = "ProductFormBeforeSubmit", // optional
    Callback = "ProductFormCallback" // optional,
};

// <form id="@formConfig.FormId" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Save"
// ...

@await Html.RenderFormScript(formConfig)
```

After that you need to add **[FormValidator]** attribute to your action.